# apt-get stuck at downloading deb file at 33%, but wget+dpkg is OK

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, apt

I use Google Cloud Artifact Registry to serve a public deb package. Recently apt-get stucks when downloading the deb file at 33%:

```
# apt-get install pkg_name_placeholder
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatasmart4 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libmm-glib0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnuma1 libparted-fs-resize0 libudisks2-0 usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pkg_name_placeholder
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 65.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://us-west2-apt.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT ppa/main amd64 pkg_name_placeholder amd64 1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b [15.3 MB]
33% [1 pkg_name_placeholder 6291 kB]
```

I tried print the download uri, `wget` and `dpkg --install` it directly and everything worked find.

```
# apt-get install --print-uris pkg_name_placeholder
# wget https://us-west2-apt.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT/pool/ppa/pkg_name_placeholder_1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b_amd64_5e5e78b0e5e5b20ae87f2abe4cd5ae88.deb
# dpkg --install pkg_name_placeholder_1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b_amd64_5e5e78b0e5e5b20ae87f2abe4cd5ae88.deb
```

Some logs after adding `-oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1`:

```
0% [Working] <- https:102 Status
URI: https://us-west2-apt.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT/pool/ppa/pkg_name_placeholder_1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b_amd64_5e5e78b0e5e5b20ae87f2abe4cd5ae88.deb
Message: Connecting to us-west2-apt.pkg.dev

 <- https:102 Status
URI: https://us-west2-apt.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT/pool/ppa/pkg_name_placeholder_1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b_amd64_5e5e78b0e5e5b20ae87f2abe4cd5ae88.deb
Message: Connecting to us-west2-apt.pkg.dev (64.233.189.82)

 <- https:102 Status
URI: https://us-west2-apt.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT/pool/ppa/pkg_name_placeholder_1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b_amd64_5e5e78b0e5e5b20ae87f2abe4cd5ae88.deb
Message: Connected to us-west2-apt.pkg.dev (64.233.189.82)

 <- https:102 Status
URI: https://us-west2-apt.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT/pool/ppa/pkg_name_placeholder_1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b_amd64_5e5e78b0e5e5b20ae87f2abe4cd5ae88.deb
Message: Waiting for headers

0% [Waiting for headers] <- https:200 URI Start
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Jun 2022 00:08:07 +0000
URI: https://us-west2-apt.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT/pool/ppa/pkg_name_placeholder_1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b_amd64_5e5e78b0e5e5b20ae87f2abe4cd5ae88.deb
Get:1 https://us-west2-apt.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT ppa/main amd64 pkg_name_placeholder amd64 1.0.0+github388~e974429020fc50435dc21d900a699717fbde470b [15.3 MB]
33% [1 pkg_name_placeholder 6291 kB]
```

After some trying, I found that if I add `-oAcquire::http::Dl-Limit=500` the download is processed and everything works fine. However, if the limit is set to a value greater than ~1000, the download gets stuck and retries.

Comment: I found several issues like this on the web, so it might be a bug. I would recommend first deleting and re-creating the troublesome package, then running that same command (with `-o Debug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1`) again until it fails. Then send the information to [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for further examination.

Comment: I just tried to add -oAcquire::http::Dl-Limit=500, and the package can be downloaded and installed. If change the limit to >1000, the download process will be stucking. This is quite wired.

Comment: I created an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/234990938

Comment: This issue is marked as solved.